# Facebook 'Like' thumbnail on mobile

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, thumbnails

Okay, so I've set a thumbnail image of 700 x 366 pixels which fits the 1.91:1 ratio fine for desktop viewing, but on the iPhone mobile app the article, once liked, gets cut down to a cropped, square image instead. Is there any way to specify a different image to use on the mobile version of Facebook?

Comment: You _can_ specify several images, but you’ll have to see if Facebook actually cares about that in that they will use _different_ images for different devices.

Comment: It doesn't. Gave up and went with a Share button instead which uses the same 1.91:1 image across the desktop and mobile app.